# How To Eliminate "withSession {implicit session: Session"

Tags: playframework-2.0, slick, play-slick

I have the following code whenever I need to access the database, which is everywhere:

```
withSession {implicit session : Session =>
    ...
}
```

How do I stop having to type so much?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a pattern for this:
http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/2.0.0-RC1/connection.html#passing-sessions-around

Also the `:Session` goes away in Slick 2.0